# Display HTMLTableElement Object returned from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a JS function that takes a 2D array and a div. It creates a table from the array and appends it to the div. The div currently displays: [object HTMLTableElement]. How can I display it as the table instead?

I call the function with: `createTable(myArray, $("#tblDiv"));`.

Later:

```
function createTable(array, tableDiv)
        {
            var tbl = document.createElement('table');
            tbl.style.border = "1px solid black";
            for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                var tr = tbl.insertRow();
                for(var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
                {
                    var td = tr.insertCell();
                }
            }
            tableDiv.append("<br>" + tbl);
            return;
        }
```

Comment: That's because you are concatenating an object with a string. > `document.createElement('table').toString() === [object HTMLTableElement]`

Comment: I am trying execute AJAX query and from the response extract table and display that on a div.

        var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(resp, "text/html")
        var data = doc.getElementById("main_table_today");
        document.getElementById("table_data").innerHTML = data.toString();
This shows [object HTMLTableElement] in 'table_data' . How do I fix this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`"<br>" + tbl` is going to evaluate to `<br>[object HTMLTableElement]`. This is string concatenation, if you try to add a string to a non string it will be converted to a string then added so an `HTMLTableElement` as a string is `[object HTMLTableElement]`.
What you want to do is append the table by itself

```
tableDiv.append("<br>");
tableDiv.append(tbl);
```

Comment: That worked and helped me fix a different error. Apparently I wasn't actually adding the values to the table. Thank you!